# Solidity: "The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance"

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Im new to Solidity, I got a problem that when I call `purchaseCard` function, it always returns the error `The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.` on Remix IDE.

I think the problem is at the complexity of my structs or I probably called variables not allowed. But I still cant find fix after many days researching.

---

These are my structs.

```
struct Card {
    string name;
    uint price;
}
mapping(uint => Card) public cards;
uint public numberOfTypes;

struct Purchase {
    Card card;
    uint purchaseDate;
}

struct User {
    uint numberOfCards;
    Purchase[] purchase;
    bool exist;
}
mapping(address => User) public users;
```

And these are my functions, I will make it short.

```
// function addCard(string memory _name, uint _price) public isOwner;
// function removeCard(uint _id) public isOwner;
// function checkExistedUser(address _userAddress) public view returns(bool);

function purchaseCard(uint _id) public {
    User storage user = users[msg.sender];
    if (!checkExistedUser(msg.sender)) {
        user.exist = true;
        user.numberOfCards = 0;
    }
    Purchase storage purchase = user.purchase[user.numberOfCards];
    purchase.card = cards[_id];
    purchase.purchaseDate = block.timestamp;
    user.numberOfCards++;
}

// function expiredCard(uint _id) public;
// function showRemainingDate(uint _id) public view returns(uint);
// function showPurchasedCards() public view returns (Purchase[] memory);
```

---

This is my full code: https://pastebin.com/4HXDZZVK

Thank you very much, I hope to learn more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you cannot create an empty 'space' for `purchase` array in storage before fill it because the type of this operation is an array and not a mapping!

To solve this issue, you can use the `push()` method (available only for storage array) to fill purchase() array into `Purchase` struct.

Following your logic, you must change `purchaseCard()` method in this way:

```
function purchaseCard(uint _id) public {
   User storage user = users[msg.sender];
   if (!checkExistedUser(msg.sender)) {
     user.exist = true;
     user.numberOfCards = 0;
   }
   user.purchase.push(Purchase(cards[_id], block.timestamp));
   user.numberOfCards++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, If you have to send/receive ETHs then the `payable` function should be used.
Try this:

```
function purchaseCard(uint _id) public payable {
```

or add `payable` to your constructor.

pls refer to this: https://solidity-by-example.org/payable/

And btw pls next time share the complete code snippet.

Comment: I tried adding it or anything before but I still does not work, Im sorry. Because Im afraid that it will be confusing and cause disliking so I made it short. I added my full code, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I can't able to understand the entire code and flow.. but while debugging..

the revert occurs in the belowline of the purchasecard function

```
 Purchase storage purchase = user.purchase[user.numberOfCards];
```

It seems like you are accessing the user mapping which does not contain any User Struct..

I think you forgot to assing the value to the user mapping in the addCard Function.

I may be wrong and I hope it helps..

Comment: thank you for caring my question and trying to help me, I found the solution below, I hope it helps you too, sir